# How to launch Cytoscape from inside Eclipse

Tags: cytoscape

I am developing an app for cytoscape but I don't know how to launch Cytoscape from inside Eclipse. Anyone help me? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tutorial about that here: https://c13s.wordpress.com/2012/05/18/set-up-an-app-project-in-eclipse-for-cytoscape-3/  Maybe that will help.

-- scooter